# Codeigniter: fetching records and sum

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following table and I am trying to display the sum of `p_total` along with all other records in the table. I have managed to display the total amount but if I display it, only values of the fist row of the table shows up. Although the sum of p_total is showing correctly as 600 .

Could you please tell me where is the problem in my code below:

Thanks in advance :)

My DB Table:

```
 p_id   p_name    p_quantity    p_rate   p_total       user_id
  1     Pepsi        12           30       360            1
  2     Hot Breads   12           20       240            1
```

I have the following code in my model

```
$this->db->select('*,SUM(temporary_table.p_total AS Total');
$this->db->from('temporary_table');
$this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);                                   
$getData = $this->db->get('');

if($getData->num_rows() > 0) {
   return $getData->result_array();
}

else { 
   return null;
}
```

This is my controller:

```
$this->load->model('mod_sales');
$data['records']= $this->mod_sales->add_to_temporary_table($user_id);
```

My View:

```
 foreach ($records as $row)
 {   
   <td><?php echo $row['p_name'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['p_quantity'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['p_rate'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['p_total'];?></td>
 }

<?php echo $row['Total'];?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your View:

```
$total_sum=0;

foreach ($records as $row){

 <td><?php echo $row['p_name'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['p_quantity'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['p_rate'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['p_total'];?></td>

 $total_sum+=$row['p_total'];
}

<?php echo $total_sum;?>
```

Comment: Using foreach is not a good solution, try extracting the result from mysql query.

Answer (score 5):

You have a total and separate list.

```
$this->db->select_sum('total_price');
$this->db->from('order');
$this->db->where('dates BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW() ');
$query=$this->db->get();
$data['total']=$query->row()->total_price;

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('order');
$this->db->where('dates BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()');
$query=$this->db->get();
$data['count']=$query->num_rows();
```

Output:

```
 Array ( 

 [total] => 2759 

 [count] => 5 

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `GROUP BY` clause.

As I understand, you want this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(p_total) FROM temporary_table WHERE user_id = ... GROUP BY p_id
```

Not familiar with CodeIgniter, but guessing you need this line after "where":

```
$this->db->group_by('p_id');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I use `$this->db->group_by('p_id'); I get the second row as well as the first row but this time the `sum` shows in correct value. It show the `p_total` value of the second row.
`

Comment: OK, I got it. You want to display rows and then total (after all rows), right? I would recommend to split this into two tasks: 1. get rows, 2. get sum (in php, you already selected all the data)